Relation between the density of states and the scattering matrix

I know the scattering matrix $S(E)$ of a system as a function of energy.
The scattering matrix relates asymptotically incoming and outgoing states of a system, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\label{eq1}
\tag{1}
\pmatrix{b^R \\ b^L } = S(E) \pmatrix{a^R \\ a^L } 
\end{align}
In this case, the density of states $\rho(E)$ is given by
\begin{align}
\label{eq2}
\tag{2}
\rho(E) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}E} \mathrm{Im} \log \det S(E + i 0^+)
\end{align}
This is true for any unitary scattering matrix, $S(E) S(E)^\dagger = \mathbb I$.
The first paper to derive this was Relation between Persistent Currents and the Scattering Matrix.
This relation appears in many papers of Prof. Carlo Beenakker, for example, in the supplement of Even-odd flux quanta effect in the Fraunhofer oscillations of an edge-channel Josephson junction.
I could not find a simple derivation of this relation or a physical reason why this relation should hold.
My question is two-fold:

How to derive Eq. (\ref{eq2})?

How to physically interpret Eq. (\ref{eq2})?



Isn't this what is known as "optical theorem" in standard QM books? There was also a rather enlightening paper by Langreth, if I am not mistaken, but axed at kondo problem.

@RogerV. I could not find any optical theorem that relates the scattering matrix to the density of states. Do you remember any references that I can go through?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_theorem
